# How to send CSV file from POSTMAN and read that file at backend in nodejs

Tags: node.js, postman

I trying to send CSV file via post request from postman but I am getting error.Please help how to send csv file from postman.[image]

Comment: Could you provide some code? What does your backend server look like?

Comment: app.post('/uploadCsv',async(req,res)=>{
  try{
    let data = req.body.fisier;
    console.log(data);
    res.status(200).send('success');
  }catch(e){
    res.status(400).send(e)
    console.log(e)
  }
})

Comment: Please edit your question to include the code, it's difficult to read in a comment.

Answer (score 1):

Because you upload file, you should add header `Content-Type: multipart/form-data` to request or update the latest postman (which automatically add header for form-data based on data type)

For example

[image]